# Writing Latex math in Word (2007)

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I only need to write equations, similar to how latex works on stack exchange.

It is very convenient to write dollar signs, write whatever math I have and then continue on writing the document as I normally would.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Word has its own Equation Editor, located under `Insert–Equation` (shortcut `Alt`+ `=`), which supports relatively advanced mathematical typesetting.

It may not be enabled by defaul. To enable it (assuming you are using Windows)

1. in `Control Panel – Uninstall a Program`;
2. find your edition of Office, and select `Change`;
3. in the Office installation menu, select  `Add/Remove Features`;
4. under `Office Tools` make sure the Equation Editor is installed.

If you prefer using LaTeX syntax directly in your Word document, consider [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word) question on Tex.SE

Comment: It is harder to use than tex. I don't want to have to click on what I want on word gui when I already can type latex. Also mathematica provides latex output immediately, which makes it easier.

Comment: Indeed, they are different. But notice that Word also allows to type symbols in a TeX-like sintax (such as `\int`, `\sum`, `\alpha`, and so on).
Also, Mathematica allows to export equations in Word's native markup, MathML, just like it allows to export equation in TeX

Comment: Oh, mathML support of mathematica is certainly very nice. I still couldn't figure out how I would do something like \sum^\inft_{n=-\infty} it doesnt detect it as the bounds of the summation. And word tries to get smart with my fractions and reorganize them.

Comment: Try typing `\sum _(n=1)^\(-infty) [space]`. Works for me. The downside is that you have to be very careful about when to press the spacebar. I much prefer typing in TeX as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable typing as in LateX like \alpha for the symbol alpha, as follows:

Go to **Options**

At **Proofing** click on **AutoCorrect Options**

Than at the *Math AutoCorrect Options* page, enable the first checkbox "Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions".

You also might give MathType a try. This is free for 30 days and is a very powerfull tool. You can use it after 30 days, but you cannot number equations anymore. In the free period, make shure to put your preferenced hotkeys to for example the multiply symbol (mine was a dot). These settings will remain after the try period. 
Enjoy!